# DAX Formula to filter the last 28 days in the table data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a measure that totals the values for each date in the table. I want to filter this measure so that I can display only the last 28 days present in the table instead of displaying values for all the dates. Following is the code that works for getting totals for full table:

```
CALCULATE( SUM(Daily_Reports[Confirmed]), 
FILTER( ALL(Daily_Reports), 
    Daily_Reports[Case_Date] = SELECTEDVALUE(Daily_Reports[Case_Date]) ) )
```

The 'relative date' filter in the Filters pane does not work because it only accepts the last 28 days based on *today's* date and not the dates in the table. Please suggest a DAX formula that can filter for the last 28 days present in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me. I created a measure (not a column), that returns 1 for the last 28 days with an IF clause, leaving it blank if the date is not in the last 28 days as follows:

```
Last28 = 
VAR MaxDate = LASTDATE( ALL(Daily_Reports[Case_Date]) ) 
VAR MinDate = DATEADD( MaxDate, -28, DAY )

RETURN
IF( SELECTEDVALUE(Daily_Reports[Case_Date]) >= MinDate && SELECTEDVALUE(Daily_Reports[Case_Date]) <= MaxDate, 1 )
```

Then I incorporated this measure into the Calculate function as follows:

```
Daily Cases = 
CALCULATE( SUM(Daily_Reports[Confirmed]), 
    FILTER( ALL(Daily_Reports), 
        Daily_Reports[Case_Date] = SELECTEDVALUE(Daily_Reports[Case_Date]) && NOT(ISBLANK(Daily_Reports[Last28])) 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
VAR endDay = LastDate(Daily_Reports[Case_Date])
VAR startDay= DATEADD(endDay,-28,DAY)
VAR setOfDates = DATESBETWEEN(Daily_Reports[Case_Date], StartDate, EndDate ) 

RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Daily_Reports[Confirmed])
        ,setOfDates 
    )
```

Comment: Returns the following error to the DATEADD function:
The first argument to DATEADD() must specify a column.

Comment: Change SelectedValue to lastdate(). As I edited it in the answer

Comment: Doesn't work either.. it not only is not filtering the dates but without the SELECTEDVALUE() function, it isn't even totaling by date. It's cumulatively adding up the totals as the dates increase.

Comment: It's something else with you data. As Ozan says you need to add at least a screenshot of the slicer. And report with my measure

Comment: Posted a screenshot of the data. Creating a measure that returns 1 and then using it in the filter function worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
MS =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Daily_Reports[Confirmed] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Daily_Reports[Case_Date] ),
        Daily_Reports[Case_Date]
            >= SELECTEDVALUE ( Daily_Reports[Case_Date] ) - 28
    )
)
```

Comment: Not working, this code totaled the entire cases for all dates and is displaying the grand total for every date.

Comment: Can you share how do you slice the table ? A screenshot would be enough.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/GtNj4dyY/Screenshot-214.png